# How to save form data as an objects and array of objects to mongodb using loop in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to MongoDB, I am using Node.js, Express 4 and mongoose(mongoDB) for my project.I stuck to save form data to mongoDB within loop and my model contains Objects and array of objects as well.

**Model** :

```
var Subscriber = new Schema({  
    first_name: String,  
    emergency_contact_1: {  
        name: String,  
        number: [{  
            type: String  
        }]  
    },  
    residential: {  
        phone: String,  
        address: String,  
        ...  
    },  
    medications: [  
    {  
        visit_id: { type: Object },  
        name: String,  
        ....  
    }],  
    food_allergies: [  
        {type: String}  
    ],  
    ....  
});
```

**Controller** :
I want to save data in this way:

```
var subscriber = new Subscriber();

//Here I am trying to save all form's fields to mongoBD fields.
for (var field in form_data) {
    subscriber[field] = form_data[field];
}

subscriber.save(function (err1, instance) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("error");
        return res.send("...");
    }
    console.log("saved successfully");
}
```

Normal fields are getting saved properly using above loop but when objects or arrays came then it won't get save to mongoDB.

Any solution ? or any other way to insert/save data through loop to mongoDB model ?
Any help would be appreciated.Thank you..!!

Comment: did you try use `Subscriber.create(form_data, callback)`?

Comment: @AndrewVolchenko I have tried and it works fine for single fields like first_name,Last_name and all.but in mongoDB model I have objects and array of objects,so at that time its not getting saved because form_data will come as individual.For eg,How can I save form_data like first_name, residential_phone, residential_address to mongoDB model like first_name: '', residential: {phone:'',address:''} using loop ??  Thank you..!!

Answer (score 0):

Nodejs

```
var PersonSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        given: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        family: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    children: [PersonSchema]
});

var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);

app.post('/person', function (req, res) {
    Person.create(req.body)
        .then(function (created) {
            console.log(created);
            res.json(created.id);
        });
});
```

Client

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/person',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        name: {
            family: 'Green'
        },
        children: [{
            name: {
                given: 'Matt',
                family: 'Green'
            }
        }, {
            name: {
                given: 'Dave',
                family: 'Green'
            }
        }]
    }
})
```

As you can see, I have nested objects and arrays. This works fine for me :)

Comment: Can you tell me what that req.body is containing ? If it's contains data from client then it wont work for me.because in my code form_data contains single fields value not object.and if not then give a snippet of it.Thank you.

Comment: @Divyesh Could you please provide an expample of your `form_data` object?

Comment: my form_data object is looks like { first_name: 'divyesh', last_name: 'dhokiya', resi_phone: '8147181480', resi_address, ec1_name: 'abc', ec1_phone: '1234567890' } and mongodb model is like above I have mention in question.Thank you..!!